# Optimization on GridServer (gs)

Tags: server

How anyone have any server or database optimization recommendations for running Craft CMS on MediaTemple's GridServer (gs)?

Since it's a shared server, I know there's not as much as you could do with a VPS or dedicated server, but I hope there is something beyond the default settings we can do to keep the site running smoothly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you - but I am curious about what you find out. [Check out this thread](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9400/recommended-hosting-company-for-a-craft-site/9415?noredirect=1#comment12464_9415) as it seems MT is troublesome with Craft. 

Unfortunate, because I too am on MT. So far my site(s) are not traffic heavy, but working on one that will have peaks so I'm not sure what to expect.

Comment: @Damon - We have been having a ton of issues with sever uptime and reliability on MediaTemple's GridServer (gs) this past week. From what the support team says, there were multiple instances of websites on our cluster going over capacity and taking down everyone else. I think at least one of those customers has been isolated or removed from our grid. At this point, we are strongly considering moving over to DigitalOcean and getting an SSD cloud server. We'll see if the uptime improves.

Comment: Let me know how it comes out. I'm not a server admin at all so moving away from MT is a bit scary.

Comment: We ended up choosing to stick with (gs) for a while. The server admin issue was important.